# Calling .Net 6 from Excel VBA, some calls are running ok others aren't

Tags: .net, vba, com

i've setup a project that uses .Net 6 and is call from excel VBA. Some of the functions work fine but others are not. Its really not clear to me why they dont work. I've tried everything i can think of many times over.

The Interface:

```
namespace COMThermoClass
{
[Guid(ContractGuids.ServerInterface)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

public interface IThermo
{
    double TestCritT();
  //  double LiqEnthalpyReal(object comps, object X, double T, double P, int method);
    double StreamEnthalpyReal(object comps, object X, double T, double P, int method);
    double StreamTemperatureReal(object comps, object X, double H, double P, int method);
    double CritP(double Tb, double SG, int method);
    double CritT(double Tb, double SG, int method);
    double DistillationPoint(object comps, object X, object SG, object BP, int method, string DistType, string distpoint);
    double EnthalpyFormationReal(object comps, object X);
    double LiqComponentEnthalpy(string comp, double T, double P, int method);
 //  double VapComponentEnthalpy(string comp, double T, double P, int method);
}
```

The class;

```
namespace COMThermoClass
{
[Guid(ContractGuids.ServerClass)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class COMThermoClass : IThermo
{
    private enumCalcResult cres;

    public COMThermoClass()
    {
        Thermodata data = new Thermodata();
    }

    public double TestCritT()
    {
        //Debugger.Launch();
        return 99.9;
    }
}
```

some function are in other files such as;

Part Partial Class code:

```
  public partial class COMThermoClass
  {
    public double LiqComponentEnthalpy(string comp, double T, double P, int method)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        double res = 0;
        BaseComp sc = Thermodata.GetRealComponent((string)comp);
        sc.molefraction = 1;
        Components cc = new Components();
        cc.Add(sc);
        cc.T = T;
        cc.P = P;

        cc.thermo.Enthalpy = (enumEnthalpy)method;

        res = ThermodynamicsClass.BulkStreamThermo(cc, cc.P, T, enumMassOrMolar.Molar,    enumFluidRegion.Liquid, ref cres).H;
        return res;
    }

    public double StreamEnthalpyReal(object comps, object X, double T, double P, int method)
    {
        double res;
        Components cc = new Components();
        cc.T = T;
        cc.P = P;
        BaseComp sc;

       // Debugger.Launch();

        string[] c = (string[])comps;
        double[] x = (double[])X;

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += x[i];
        }

        if (sum != 1)  // normalise
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] /= sum;
            }
        }

        cc.thermo.Enthalpy = (enumEnthalpy)method;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            sc = Thermodata.GetRealComponent(c[i]);
            if (sc == null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Component " + c[i].ToString() + "Not Found In Database");
            }
            else
            {
                sc.molefraction = x[i];
                cc.Add(sc);
            }
        }

        BasicPropList bpl = new BasicPropList();

        bpl.T.BaseValue = T;
        bpl.P.BaseValue = P;

        bpl.T.origin = SourceEnum.Input;
        bpl.P.origin = SourceEnum.Input;

        FlashClass.Flash(cc, bpl, false);

        res = cc.BulkEnthalpy();
        return res;
    }
    public double StreamTemperatureReal(object comps, object X, double H, double P, int method)
    {
        double res;
        Components cc = new Components();
        cc.P = P;
        BaseComp sc;

        //Debugger.Launch();

        string[] c = (string[])comps;
        double[] x = (double[])X;

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += x[i];
        }

        if (sum != 1)  // normalise
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] /= sum;
            }
        }

        cc.thermo.Enthalpy = (enumEnthalpy)method;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            sc = Thermodata.GetRealComponent(c[i]);
            if (sc == null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Component " + c[i].ToString() + "Not Found In Database");
            }
            else
            {
                sc.molefraction = x[i];
                cc.Add(sc);
            }
        }

        BasicPropList bpl = new BasicPropList();

        bpl.H.BaseValue = H;
        bpl.P.BaseValue = P;

        bpl.H.origin = SourceEnum.Input;
        bpl.P.origin = SourceEnum.Input;

        FlashClass.Flash(cc, bpl, false);

        res = cc.T;
        return res;
    }
    public double StreamComponentEnthalpy(string c, double T, double P, int method)
    {
        double res;
        Components cc = new Components();
        cc.T = T;
        cc.P = P;
        BaseComp sc;

        cc.thermo.Enthalpy = (enumEnthalpy)method;
        sc = Thermodata.GetRealComponent(c);

        if (sc == null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Component " + c.ToString() + "Not Found In Database");
        }
        else
        {
            sc.molefraction = 1;
            cc.Add(sc);
        }
       
        BasicPropList bpl = new BasicPropList();

        bpl.T.BaseValue = T;
        bpl.P.BaseValue = P;

        bpl.T.origin = SourceEnum.Input;
        bpl.P.origin = SourceEnum.Input;

        FlashClass.Flash(cc, bpl, false);

        res = cc.BulkEnthalpy();
        return res;
    }
```

The IDL file

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
//
// typelib filename: COMThermo.tlb

[
  uuid(A5996396-7DB2-44B4-BD98-4D769792DE2D),
  version(1.0),
  custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6286C, "COMThermo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

]
library COMThermo
{
    // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    interface ICOMThermo;

    [
      odl,
      uuid(B221E497-C862-4C40-B4E6-5D79E7AB28D5),
      version(1.0),
      oleautomation,
      custom(B10B0742-6D84-415D-894C-798ED2D76C1D, "COMThermo.ICOMThermo")

    ]
    interface ICOMThermo : IUnknown {
        [id(0x60020000)]
        HRESULT _stdcall TestCritT([out, retval] double* pRetVal);
        [id(0x60020001)]
        HRESULT _stdcall StreamEnthalpyReal(
            [in] VARIANT comps,
            [in] VARIANT X,
            [in] double T,
            [in] double P,
            [in] long method,
            [out, retval] double* pRetVal);
        [id(0x60020002)]
        HRESULT _stdcall StreamTemperatureReal(
            [in] VARIANT comps,
            [in] VARIANT X,
            [in] double H,
            [in] double P,
            [in] long method,
            [out, retval] double* pRetVal);
        [id(0x60020003)]
        HRESULT _stdcall LiqEnthalpyReal(
            [in] VARIANT comps,
            [in] VARIANT X,
            [in] double T,
            [in] double P,
            [in] long method,
            [out, retval] double* pRetVal);
        [id(0x60020004)]
        HRESULT _stdcall LiqComponentEnthalpy(
            [in] BSTR comps,
            [in] double T,
            [in] double P,
            [in] long method,
            [out, retval] double* pRetVal);
    };
    [
      uuid(BE532448-9A5A-4273-B93C-0573545D36C4),
      version(1.0),
      custom(B10B0742-6D84-415D-894C-798ED2D76C1D, "COMThermo.COMThermo")
    ]
    coclass COMThermo {
        interface _Object;
        [default] interface ICOMThermo;
    };
};
```

The Excel VBA

```
  Dim test As New COMThermo.COMThermo

Function Test1()
    Test1 = test.TestCritT()
End Function

Sub LiqComponentEnthalpy()

Dim res As Double

res = test.LiqComponentEnthalpy("n-Butane", 25 + 273.15, 1#, 5)

'End Function
End Sub

Function StreamEnthalpy(comp As Range, Xfractions As Range, T As Double, P As Double, Method As Integer) As Double
Dim Names() As String
Dim x() As Double

No = comp.Cells.Count
ReDim Names(No - 1)
ReDim x(No - 1)

For i = 1 To No
    Names(i - 1) = comp(i).Value
    x(i - 1) = Xfractions(i).Value
Next

StreamEnthalpy = test.StreamEnthalpyReal(Names, x, T + 273.15, P, Method)

'End Function
End Function
```

When i run the VBA "TestTcrit" works fine as does "StreamEnthalpy" but "LiqComponentEnthlapy" give an error saying "Runtime error -2147467261 "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any possible deas why?

Comment: From your code, it's probable the "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" happens in the function "LiqComponentEnthalpy" itself. Why I don't know but this function probably causes the error. If you can't have a full stack trace from VBA, try to debug it from the loading process (excel maybe)

Comment: Thanks Simon, I emptied that method so it just returns a fixed value and get the same error.  On another occasion the VBA (slightlty different example than this one) was actually calling the wrong method even though names all looked correct.  Maybe trying to do COM with .net 6 is just too buggy.

Comment: Some things have changed between .NET framework and .NET Core3/5/6 with regards to COM support, but they are more (sometimes painful) breaking changes, not weird or strange unreproducible errors. You should post your a reproducing code somewhere for further investigation.

Comment: Hi sorry im not sure what you mean, all the code is posted above or do you mean post it somewhere else?

I have also just created a simple example with 6 test methods thats works perfectly, its confusing.

Comment: The code may be there, but it's too much work to copy paste it trying to reproduce.

Comment: I think i got.  Its the order of the methods as declared in the C# class interface and the order they are in the IDL file...  You can have more methods in the Class interface file than are in the IDL file but they must be after all the ones in the IDL file...

Comment: Yes, the order of methods of an IUnknown-derived interface is meaningful. So you must make sure they are the same when you declare it in C#. This has nothing to do with .NET Core vs .NET Framework.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming.

Comment: Just don't re-declare the interface in the C# code.  Add a reference to the generated .tlb file instead, ensures the method declarations and order are always identical.

Comment: I'm not sure understand what you mean.  I can't add a reference to it in Visual Studio (or can i somehow??) Excel allready has a reference to the tlb.  Can you elaborate please?